# Class "StudentController" does not exist

Tags: laravel

im working with laravel in a crud project and i have to create the route for a controller but i keep getting this error:
Class "StudentController" does not exist
[image]

The thing is it does exist and its locate in the correct location, what can i do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: If you read the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/controllers#resource-controllers), you will see you have to use `StudentController::class`, not `'StudentContoller'`...

Answer (score 3):

the way you use it is wrong.
you have to import the namespace of the controller not just the name of the controller.

```
Route::resource('student', StudentController::class);
```

change your code like so. this should fix the issue